# Missing Files after Photos Import

Tags: photos, import

I imported pictures from my phone, and my pictures are now in a file called "missing files". How can I restore these pictures?

Comment: More info would be helpful. Maybe screen capture.

Comment: I've had the same issue but importing from the IPhoto on the Mac. No time to take a screen shot. The package comes up and instantly closes down again.